# Menu bar scrolling not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a flyover dropdown menu and when I scroll down the page this menu need to appear all the time. I have this below code which is working fine for FFox and chrome but IE8 and I hope IE9 its not working. Not sure whats causing the issue. Please suggest if any change need to be done to work with IE as well

```
var name = ".cssMenu";
//var menuYloc = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    //menuYloc = parseInt($(name).css("top").substring(0,$(name).css("top").indexOf("px")))
    $(window).scroll(function () { 
    if($(this).scrollTop()>70){

        offset =$(document).scrollTop()-70+"px";
        }
        else
        {
        offset = $(document).scrollTop()+"px";
        }

        $(name).css("top",offset);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i blind shoot suspect it being the order its executed. try wrapping it in `()` like:

```
`offset =($(document).scrollTop()-70)+"px";`
```